# Inserting in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having a small difficulty inserting a full sentence containing all characters in my string when I'm building a Linked List.

I would like to be able to insert a string like: `word_#_2003_#_definition`
But when I'm running my code in my `main()` method it continues repeating the choices to do like it never stops asking me to enter an option. Hope it's clear.

Here's my `struct`:

```
struct node
{
    char data[100];
    struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
    struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
} *head, *last;
```

Here's my function to insert a node:

```
void insert_beginning(char words[99])
{
    struct node *var, *temp;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //explination about the (node *)
    strncpy(var->data, words,99);

    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->previous=NULL;
        head->next=NULL;
        last=head;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=var;
        temp->previous=NULL;
        temp->next=head;
        head->previous=temp;
        head=temp;
    }
}
```

And this is in my `main()` method:

```
int main()
{
    char loc[99];
    char words[99];
    int i, dat;

    head=NULL;

    printf("Select the choice of operation on link list");
    printf("\n1.) Insert At Begning\n2.) Insert At End\n3.) Insert At Middle");
    printf("\n4.) Delete From End\n5.) Reverse The Link List\n6.) Display List\n7.)Exit");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\n Enter the choice of operation you want to do ");
        scanf("%d",&i);

        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Enter a word you want to insert in the 1st node ");
                scanf(" %s",words);

                insert_beginning(words);
                display();
                break;
            }
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Your code is not complete!

Comment: Maybe because of the while loop?

Comment: Where's the logic that exits the while loop?

Comment: @keshlam he didn't included the whole code! can't you see that the switch and the while are note closed

Comment: Your problem is that `scanf()` reads just one space delimited word, and leaves behind the second, then the `scanf()` for the number fails to convert (but you didn't check the return from `scanf()`, so you don't know that), and goes back to the `switch/case` to read the next word, etc.  This is not what you had in mind, but it is what you wrote.

Comment: @rullof Exactly. I'm just pointing out exactly why he's handicapped himself by doing so.

Comment: should i paste the full code then?

Comment: As a matter of idle observation, I don't think you need the variable `temp` in the insert code; you could replace each reference to `temp` with `var` and I think it would work the same (though you'd skip the self-assignment, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The code is highly questionable:

- return codes are never checked. You must check return codes,
  especially if you are   using scanf
- You need to empty the whole buffer with scanf otherwise you will continue
  reading old contents for the next command
- A better alternative is to use sscanf
- You must initialize your variables, for instance last, but there are additional
  cases of variables that do not get initialized
- Your data types are not consistently defined, this will create security problems
  sometimes 99 characters and sometimes 100.
- insert_beginning should not return void, the memory allocation can fail

Comment: Since the input code has 99 and the loner-term storage structure has 100, there isn't a problem during input operations.  If the value is fetched from the data structure into a 99-character buffer, there could be a problem if the extra byte had somehow been exploited to make the string overlong.  Don't get me wrong: consistency is very important in programming in general, but the risk here is low.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `main()` should probably look more like:

```
int main()
{
    char loc[99];
    char words[99];
    int i, dat;

    head = NULL;

    printf("Select the choice of operation on link list");
    printf("\n1.) Insert At Beginning\n2.) Insert At End\n3.) Insert At Middle");
    printf("\n4.) Delete From End\n5.) Reverse The Link List\n6.) Display List\n7.) Exit\n");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the choice of operation you want to do: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a number: exiting\n");
            return 1;
        }

        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Enter a word you want to insert in the 1st node: ");
                if (scanf("%98s", words) != 1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read words; exiting\n");
                    return 1;
                }

                insert_beginning(words);
                display();
                break;
            }
            ...
         }
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As discussed in the comments, you are not checking the return status from `scanf()`, so you don't know when it is failing, and when it fails to read a number, it leaves the argument (`i`) alone, so you go back to the same option again, and rinse and repeat.

Elementary debugging techniques (not shown):

1. Print the values you get from your inputs.  Print the value of `i` after the `scanf()` error checking.  Print the value of `words` after the `scanf()` error checking.
2. Step through with a debugger.
3. Create a function to dump (print) your key data structures:

   ```
   static void dump_data_structure(FILE *fp, char const *tag, data_structure const *data)
   {
       ...code to dump the structure to the specified file stream,
       ...identified by tag (so you can tell which call it is you are looking at)
   }
   ```
4. Use the structure dumper extensively while debugging. Keep it for use later when modifying the code.  If done right, it can be enormously helpful.

Comment: This code is still problematic. If the user enters more than one word on a line it will ignore the other words or if unlucky use a string as a command.

Comment: @steve: Yes -- the revised code is not perfect, but it will check the return value from `scanf()` and head off trouble earlier. It would be possible to revise the code to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, amongst other alternatives, but it probably won't help him all that much at the moment (and he'd still need to check the input functions for errors).  He can type (on a single line `1 Word 2 Alter 3 Ego 4 7` and the program will go through a number of operations before exiting, all from a single line of input.  That's the way the code is currently designed; I didn't fix it to do otherwise.